# Start SVG animation from React prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I am wondering if there is a way to start animations from a prop in React.

```
type ComponentProps= {
  startAnimation: boolean;
}
class Component extends React.PureComponent<ComponentProps>
{
  ...
  render()
  {
    return <svg
      ..
        <animate begin={this.props.startAnimation ? What goes here? : "indefinite"} />
    </svg>;
  }
}
```

I have looked extensively over the internet and it seems like there are ways of starting SVG animations but not from a React component prop, or more generally, a variable.

I found this on StackOverflow:
[SVG animate starts without being started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64928298/svg-animate-starts-without-being-started)

The issue is that the using an event in the begin attribute is not what I want, using beginElement() throws an error "Property beginElement() does not exist on type Element", and wallclock() is not supported by any browser. [SVG animation begin at wallclock-sync-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894809/svg-animation-begin-at-wallclock-sync-value)

The other solution is to use CSS animations or their respective libraries which are cumbersome.
I'm unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

[framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/) could be what you are looking for, and not too much conversion.

Just need to change `<svg>` to `<motion.svg>` etc, and you can use their animate, hidden, and variant props to start/stop different animations.framer